# "Beaver" joke in PTA's "Licorice Pizza"

Tags: dialogue, licorice-pizza

In the 2021 movie *Licorice Pizza* by Paul Thomas Anderson, the main character Gary makes an awkward joke that, as far as I could understand, goes like this (not verbatim):

> (on the TV show stage)
>
> - Host: How are things going for you, Gary?
> - Gary: Last week I did three beavers.
> - Host: You mean *Leave it to Beaver*?
> - Gary: *Three* beavers.

Can someone explain to me as a non-native English speaker and non-American what Gary is referring to here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"Beaver" is a euphemism for female genitalia. Still used, but more common in the early 70s. I would say using "Leave it to Beaver" (the TV show) in a joke of this nature was about as commonplace as jokes about Uranus.

Comment: I'd say ‘beaver’ is slang (already dated at the time of the story), not a euphemism. Euphemisms are what you say to *avoid* vulgarity, and ‘beaver’ is not that.

Comment: After noticing that he says he *did* three beavers and with this answer, the joke is now clear to me.

Comment: Do you want to know more? https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18810/how-did-the-word-beaver-come-to-be-associated-with-vagina

Answer (score 3):

Continuing from the first answer, he's implying that he had sex three times.

Comment: This was already implied through the existing answer. Please use comments to address other answers. You can take the [Tour] to familiarize yourself with this platform. Welcome to Movies & TV!

Comment: Disagree @Joachim.  It is not implied at all.  It is not spelled out, nor understood.

Comment: @JasonPSallinger Hence "implied" :) But sure, that's subjective. I just think that apart from that this is a comment, not an answer - the OP asks what is referenced in the dialogue.

Comment: For me, this is a very helpful amendment to the other answer. It explains the emphasis on *three*.